# How to NIntegrate the result of NDSolveValue over the IVs?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, functional

I want to integrate functional `g` of the solution of `f` over the IVs.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

p = {4, 1};
E1 = 0;
E2 = -1;

f[p_, t_] := {x'[t] == y[t]/p[[2]], y'[t] == -p[[1]]*x[t]};

g[x_, p_, t_] := 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[E1, 1], x[[1]]]*
  PDF[NormalDistribution[E2, 1], x[[2]]];

h[xf_, p_, tau_] := Module[{sol, tmp, J},
   sol = 
    NDSolveValue[
     Flatten[{f[p, t], {x[0] == xf[[1]], y[0] == xf[[2]]}}], {x[t], 
      y[t]}, {t, 2*Pi, 0}];
   tmp = sol /. t -> 2*Pi - tau;
   Print[tmp];
   J = Abs[1];
   Return[g[tmp, p, 0]*J];
   ];

(* first coordinate is fixed to 1 *)
NIntegrate[h[{1, y}, p, 1], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

However, it fails with

```
NDSolveValue::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments.

NDSolveValue::dsvar: -1+2 \[Pi] cannot be used as a variable.

NDSolveValue[{(x^\[Prime])[-1+2 \[Pi]]==y[-1+2 \[Pi]],(y^\[Prime])[-1+2 \[Pi]]==-4 x[-1+2 \[Pi]],x[0]==1,y[0]==y},{x[-1+2 \[Pi]],y[-1+2 \[Pi]]},{-1+2 \[Pi],2 \[Pi],0}]
```

and the `y[0]==y` part looks like that `NIntegrate` puts a symbol instead of value.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There are two issues: (1) scoping of `y`, (2) attempt to integrate symbolically. Fix the first one by changing the integration variable, for example: `NIntegrate[h[{1, yy}, p, 1], {yy, -Infinity, Infinity}]`. Fix the second one by restricting `h` only to numerical values of arguments, e.g. `h[xf : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, p_, tau_] := ...`. Regarding the second issue, there are several questions on this SE (search for "numericq").

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Domen ! Very concise and useful!